# is this right way of opening a .txt file

Tags: c

This part of code is responsiable for opening my data.txt file and reading a couple numbers from it (size of arrays and numbers to fill it with) but both Virtual Programming Lab and C say "**can not find the program "" in executable files**". I tried this way by writing a program what will only read 1 number from .txt and same error appeares so i guess im doing this completely wrong. Is there any other way of reading from .txt file? Thanks

```
Array* input() {

int x,y;
int i;
Array *p;

FILE *f=fopen("data.txt", "r");

p = (Array*) malloc(sizeof(Array));

fscanf(f, "&d",&x);
fscanf(f, "&d",&y);

p->n1 = x;
p->n2 = y;
p->p1 = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * p->n1);
p->p2 = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * p->n2);
for(i=0; i < p->n1; i++)
fscanf(f, "%d", &p->p1[i]);
for(i=0; i < p->n2; i++)
fscanf(f, "%d", &p->p2[i]);
fclose(f);
return p;
}
```

Comment: The error message from the build system looks unrelated to any problems in the source code. Did you set the name of the output program in your development environment? The code itself looks more-or-less OK apart from the complete lack of error checking, and you used `p1` instead of `p2` in the second `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks Ian, missed that mistake in second loop. Then it must be the outputs problem because now I run out of memory sometimes when i try to run program, it must be that im not printing array correctly.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and show us some example input.

Comment: when asking a question about a run time problem, as this question is doing, post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: OT: regarding this kind of statement: `p->p1 = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * p->n1);` 1) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, then call `perror( "your error message" );`  to output both your error message AND the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`

Comment: What is the definition of: `Array`?  What header files are being included?  Where is the `main()` function?

Comment: OT: regarding this kind of statement: `fscanf(f, "&d",&x);`  always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  The `scanf()` family of functions returns the number of successful 'input format conversion specifiers`  In this case, any returned value other than 1 indicates an error

Comment: OT:  regarding: `FILE *f=fopen("data.txt", "r");`   always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call: `perror( "fopen for data.txt failed" );` to output to `stderr` both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.

Comment: where is the `main()` function, that calls `input()`?

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. may cause the compiler to output: "untitled.c:114:9: warning: unused variable ‘ptrToArray’ [-Wunused-variable]"
2. performs the desired functionality
3. properly checks for I/O errors
4. properly cleans up after any I/O error
5. separates the definition of the struct from the typedef for that struct, for flexibility
6. the function: `malloc()` expects a parameter of type `size_t`. This results in several other changes being needed from `int` to `size_t`
7. for ease of readability and understanding: separates code blocks: `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line
8. for readability, inserts a space around C operators, inside parens, after commas, after semicolons, inside braces, inside brackets
9. follows the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*
10. properly declares the parameter list for function: `input()` as `void`
11. for readability (by humans) consistently indents the code.  indents after every opening brace '{'.  Unindents before every closing brace '}'. Uses a indent width of 4 spaces.
12. for ease of readability and understanding: separates functions via 2 blank lines.
13. limits the scope of local variable `i` to the code block it is declared within rather than to the scope of the function: `input()`

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct array
{
    size_t n1;
    size_t n2;
    int *p1;
    int *p2;
};
typedef struct array ARRAY;


ARRAY* input( void ) 
{
    size_t x;
    size_t y;

    ARRAY *p;

    FILE *f = fopen( "data.txt", "r" );
    if( !f )
    {
        perror( "fopen for reading data.txt failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    p = malloc( sizeof(ARRAY) );
    if( !p )
    {
        perror( "malloc for an instance of struct array failed" );
        fclose( f );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    if( fscanf( f, "%zu", &x ) != 1 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "fscanf for first data from file failed\n" );
        fclose( f );
        free( p->p1 );
        free( p->p2 );
        free( p );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    if( fscanf( f, "%zu", &y ) != 1 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "fscanf for second data from file failed\n" );
        fclose( f );
        free( p );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }


    p->n1 = x;
    p->n2 = y;

    p->p1 = malloc(sizeof(int) * p->n1);
    if( !p->p1 )
    {
        perror( "malloc failed for pointer 'p1'" );
        free( p );
        fclose( f );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    p->p2 = malloc(sizeof(int) * p->n2);
    if( !p->p2 )
    {
        perror( "malloc failed for pointer 'p2'" );
        free( p->p1 );
        free( p );
        fclose( f );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    for( size_t i=0; i < p->n1; i++ )
    {
        if( fscanf(f, "%d", &p->p1[i]) != 1 )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "fscanf for %zu value in array 'p1' failed\n", i );
            fclose(f);
            free( p->p1 );
            free( p->p2 );
            free( p );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    }

    for( size_t i=0; i < p->n2; i++ )
    {
        if( fscanf(f, "%d", &p->p2[i]) != 1 )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "fscanf for %zu value in array 'p2' failed\n", i );
            fclose(f);
            free( p->p1 );
            free( p->p2 );
            free( p );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    }

    fclose(f);

    return p;
}


int main( void )
{
    ARRAY *ptrToArray = input();
    free( ptrToArray->p1 );
    free( ptrToArray->p2 );
    free( ptrToArray );
    return 0;
}
```